# JavaScript JSON stringify: make it output a one-line compact string

Tags: javascript, json, stringify

I'm trying to create a custom function for converting a JSON object to a one-line string. For example:

```
var obj = {
 "name": "John Doe",
 "age": 29,
 "location": "Denver Colorado",
};
```

I would like to make it output: `"{ \"name\": \"John Doe\", \"age\": 29, \"location\": \"Denver Colorado,\"}"`

My function below does not work, which makes me wonder how to remove the new lines (hidden) in the output:

```
function objToCompactString(obj) {
        var result = "\"{";
        Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
            result += `"${key}":"${obj[key]}",`;
        });

        result += "}\"";
        return result;
}
```

Comment: By the way what you are showing there is not "a JSON object".  That is a javascript object. JSON (by definition) is a string representation of javascript objects and in it's default implementation (before you try to rewrite it) it produces a single line string.

Comment: interesting .. a question that has the answer in the title

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You may want to have a look at [JSON.stringify](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify).

In your case:

```
var obj = {
    "name": "John Doe",
    "age": 29,
    "location": "Denver Colorado",
};
var result = JSON.stringify(obj);
console.log(result);
```

Comment: silly me, I first tried `JSON.stringify`, but it gave me multiple lines of string, which made me painstakingly reinvent the wheel. lol. thank you thank you :)

Comment: @TonyGW The third argument to `stringify` controls how the string is displayed with newlines and spaces.